# How to read a text file into an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to read in a text file using `FileReader`.

The text file to be read is the same as the one which is written to using the `StoreData` procedure.

I am trying to get the program to read in the names from the `.txt` file and put them into the `'mainName'` string in the `Room` class (see below).

Obviously each name being read in from the text file would require a separate '`Room`' object. Please correct the code in the '`loadData`' procedure

```
public class HotelObjects {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String command;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
    for (int x = 0; x < myHotel.length; x++) {
    myHotel[x] = new Room();
    }

    String roomName;
    int roomNum = 0;

    while (roomNum < 11) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter command : ");
        command = input.next();
        command = command.toLowerCase();

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'v') {
            viewCustomers(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'a') {
            addCustomers(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'e') {
            emptyRooms(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 's') {
            storeData(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'l') {
            loadData(myHotel);
        }

    }
}

private static void viewCustomers(Room hotelRef []) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + hotelRef[x].getName());
        }
}

private static void addCustomers(Room myHotel[]) {
    String roomName;
    int roomNum;
    System.out.println("Enter room number (0-10) or 11 to stop:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        roomNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " :");
        roomName = input.next();
        myHotel[roomNum].setName(roomName);
}

private static void emptyRooms(Room[] myHotel) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
        if (myHotel[x].getName().equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
}

private static void storeData(Room [] myHotel) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("HotelObjects.txt");
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        writer.write(myHotel[x].getName());
        writer.write("\r\n");
    }
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("File 'HotelObjects.txt' saved to C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HotelObjects");
}


private static void loadData(Room[] myHotel) throws Exception {
    int lineCount =0 ;
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Hotel\\HotelArray.txt")));
        String fileLine;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            fileLine = sc.nextLine();
            myHotel[fileLine].setName();
            lineCount++;
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("File 'HotelArray.txt' loaded from C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Hotel");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
}
```

This is the Room class:

```
public class Room {


private String mainName;
int guestsInRoom;

public Room() {
    mainName = "e";
    System.out.println("made a room ");
}

public void setName(String aName) {
    mainName = aName;
}

public String getName() {
    return mainName;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the *problem* you are facing?

Comment: There is an error on this line:   myHotel[fileLine].setName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myHotel[fileLine].setName();
```

*firstly* needs a *string argument as defined here:*,

```
public void setName(String aName) {
```

*You are calling it without an argument* which will obviously `lead to an error and your code will not compile and run.`

and *secondly* it needs an integer argument for *myHotel[]*

*If you want to set the name to the line string and use lineCount as the integer index then change it to this:*

```
myHotel[lineCount].setName(fileLine);
```

Or you can use another `index` to replace `lineCount` but it *must be an integer number*. Then it *should* work.

Comment: Can you show me how the entire procedure should look now (i'm still getting compiling problems)

Comment: see my update. you need to use an integer to index your table, not a string as you are currently using... You could use lineCount for example, which is an integer. Hope it works now

Comment: show me the input of the txt file you try to load (HotelArray.txt)

Comment: Don't worry, sorted it. It was a basic syntax issue on my part.

Answer (score 0):

fileLine is a String. You cannot use a String as an array index like so:

```
String fileLine;
... (modify fileLine)
myHotel[fileLine].setName();
```

If you want to map a String to an object, you can use a Map.

You need to use an integer as an array index. e.g:

```
myHotel[4].setName();
```

Also setName() accepts a String parameter and you are not passing it any parameter. It should be used like this:

```
 myHotel[4].setName("some string");
```

Therefore there are two errors on this line: `myHotel[fileLine].setName();`